# Suite Script for User Event is not getting triggered for xedit operaration

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a SuiteScript which is getting triggered on AfterSubmit of any Case update. It is working fine for normal updates.

But when I try to edit a Case in-line(through case search), the event is not getting triggered.

Do I need to configure anything specific to handle the in-line edit during the script deployment?

Please find the script which I am using to identify the xedit operation.

```
function handleSupportCaseCreateUpdateReqeust(type, form, request) {
    try {        
        if(type == 'xedit'){
            nlapiLogExecution('AUDIT', 'TFSNSIntegrator Log', 'Type of the event is :'+ type);
        }
} catch (e) {
        nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'Exception', e.message);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger in NetSuite. Unless this is a client-script, in which case, you should be able to simply inspect execution.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your script deployment ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple thought, but may as well check - have you confirmed that your Deployment's Log Level is set to Audit? If not, that could be why you aren't seeing that in the execution log.

Comment: Yes, if you have set your Script Deployment's Status to _Released_, then NetSuite will automatically change the Log Level to _Error_. You may need to verify this and set the Log Level back to _Audit_ or _Debug_ accordingly.

Comment: I tried with both "Audit" & "Debug", but both didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Through NetSuite Support, I figured out the issue.

The issue was with the option I selected to deploy the SuiteScript. I selected 'Edit' event to trigger the script, since we dont have a option "xedit". Actually we should not select any particular event. I just deployed it with our selecting any specific event and it started to work.

Thanks all for your replies!